# Stacking multiple Alpha Planes

Tags: cycles-render-engine, transparency

I have a simple scene where I have simple planes and textures using the alpha channel of the PNG as transparency.

[image]

The way I created the files makes the Alpha channel 000 black and 255 pure white. Here is one texture if you want to examine it.

[image]

---

When I prepare a scene using cycles, it works fine.

[image]

I can add more planes this way.

[image]

But when I add a third one, the intersection of the planes begin to form a shadow.

[image]

Stacking 4 planes make the shadow obvious. It is rendered on the spot where the images are combined.

[image]

Here is [the blend file without textures](http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=49892).

What settings can I change? I changed bounce samples... but this is not about bouncing...

Any tips?

Comment: did you increase the number for Transparent bounces? https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvPeA.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently you have a maximum of 4 transparency bounces:

[image]

So after 4 transparent surfaces overlap you will get errors.

You need to increase the number of transparency bounces so that there are as many as transparent surfaces a ray has to go throuugh:

[image]