# Alpha channels in cycles canceling out each other

Tags: cycles-render-engine, transparency

I have two images with alpha channels that overlay each other. In Eeevee it works fine but in cycles, the front image's alpha channel blocks out the image behind it. Is this something that can be fixed by some adjustment in the cycles settings?

Thanks,
Rusty

Comment: Please show an image that shows what you get. It might be an issue with not enough transparency bounces. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/112449/stacking-multiple-alpha-planes/112451#112451

Comment: Somehow susu's comment didn't show up when I wrote my answer. I guess that's the reason. But since you said "images" and images are no mesh objects, there might be other possible solutions. Are those images with their alphas the textures for planes? Do those planes lie in the same location? Intersecting/overlapping polygons often cause problems - but in this case the Eevee version should look incorrect, too.

Answer (score 1):

One possible reason could be that in the Cycles render settings the "Max Bounces" for "Transparency" are set too low. Since Eevee is not a raytracing engine it doesn't need those settings. The default settings however should be high enough. With two images Transparency bounces must be set to 0 to block out the underlying image.

Comment: Thank you. I figured it out.