# Blender 2.9 Cycles: Render issue with Alpha Masked Leaves on Trees

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, transparency

I recently purchased some tree models from Globe Plants specifically for Blender Cycles Render. I'm hoping to get a response from them directly but thought I'd ask if anyone else knew what was happening. Some of the models I've purchased from them look great but the Trees are having alpha issues with the leaves. In most cases, the leaves are transparent and the black alpha portion of the material is visible. It's even worse when back lit. Screen shots of the trees, nodes and display settings are attached. I've tried changing the material settings from Opaque to Alpha Clip but that doesn't seem to be the issue.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLeZf.jpg)

[image]

[image]

[image][image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Black artifacts when looking through many transparent objects?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27718/black-artifacts-when-looking-through-many-transparent-objects)

Comment: Increase the number of transparent (or transission) bounces

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/112449/stacking-multiple-alpha-planes?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I do not believe it's an issue with Light Paths. I increased both Transparent & Transmission to 20 with no difference in render. Also, I have Bushes and other plants with multiple leaves that look fine. The material node setup appears to be the same as the trees but it's only the tree models that have the issue.

Comment: Susu that is not the problem. I just rendered with both set to 1024, the max. Absolutely no change. I should also mention that the bush objects that look perfect in final render, with many many leaves in front of one another also look perfect in the viewport shading render mode. The trees look the same in both as well but look as shown above. Leaves that are not layered in front of other leaves are transparent. The ones where the leaves are visible are backed by other leaves but in both cases, you still see the black alpha channel.